# How to compile Ubuntu 16.04 kernel with zfs module

Tags: kernel, compiling, zfs

I build custom Ubuntu kernel with make localmodconfig at the Ubuntu 16.04 lts server with installing zfs and mounted zfs pool.

```
make localmodconfig
using config: '.config'
zfs config not found!!
rdma_cm config not found!!
znvpair config not found!!
zavl config not found!!
spl config not found!!
zunicode config not found!!
zcommon config not found!!
```

So it is not surprise for me to get after reboot with builded kernel system report that zfs mount failed.

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module zfs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.8-passthrough
```

There is no options related to ZFS in .config file and make menuconfig.
Where can I get missed configs for zfs, rdma_cm, znvpair, zavl, spl, zunicode, zcommon or what trick should I do for bulding kernel with ZFS?

Thanks in advanced.
Igor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because building custom kernels is off-topic at this site.

Comment: This is not off topic as the question relates to building the Ubuntu 16.04 kernel - which is not a custom kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

Install the necessary tools and dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
sudo apt-get build-dep linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

clone the Xenial Ubuntu linux 4.4 kernel:

```
git clone https://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/xenial
```

and build the kernel:

```
cd xenial
sudo apt-get install kernel-wedge
fakeroot debian/rules clean
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev ncurses-dev xz-utils kernel-package
debian/rules build
faketroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

and you should end up with the necessary linux image and headers